# position fixed apenas na horizontal

Tags: css

Estou com uma dúvida, queria saber se é possível deixar minha `div` com `position: fixed` apenas na horizontal e na vertical não...

É possivel fazer isso?

```css
.body{
  height: 1500px;
  width: 1500px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só usar `position:sticky` com o `left` como referencia, e deixar sem `top`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima.

```css
.body{
  height: 1500px;
  width: 1500px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: sticky;
  /* top: 25px; */
  left: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Salvou minha vida kk. Obrigado

Comment: @OtavioCapel sem problemas :D 